# TinyMCE codesample plugin in WordPress doesn't work on post view page

Tags: php, wordpress, tinymce, tinymce-4

I try too add code highlighting for blog with TinyMCE 4.3.1 capabilities. At first I don't understand why I don't have this plugin in `wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins` folder after WP update, so I have to insert it manually.

I added such filter:

```
function mytheme_tinymce_settings( $settings ) {
    $settings['plugins'] .= ",codesample";
    $settings['toolbar1'] .= ",codesample";

    return $settings;
}
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'mytheme_tinymce_settings' );
```

So now I have button to add code snippets and it highlighted well in editor field, but when I publish post simple pre appears.
When I add filter than `/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/codesample/plugin.min.js?wp-mce-4310-20160418` appears in both pages: edit page and post view page, but works only for edit page.

How to make it work on post view page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
function mytheme_tinymce_settings( $settings ) {
    $settings['plugins'] .= ",codesample";
    $settings['toolbar1'] .= ",codesample";

    return $settings;
}
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'mytheme_tinymce_settings' );
```

Adds button in tinyMCE.

```
wp_enqueue_style('prism','/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/codesample/css/prism.css');
wp_enqueue_script('prism_js',plugins_url( 'js/run_code_highlighting.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery'));
```

Adds js and css files on page(I created small plugin for this).

```
jQuery(window).load( function() {
    tinymce.codesampleplugin.Prism.highlightAll();
});
```

Run prism highlighting for all elements on page (document ready doesn't work - tinymce.codesampleplugin is null at this moment).

P.S. Can be a little bit tricky to add highlighting in comments if you don't refresh page after comment update for example.

Comment: The original question clearly stated the error - wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/codesample/plugin.min.js NOT FOUND. It is still the same error. Since this is plugin, nothing stated, about how how the css will be dropped to that location.

Comment: @Jay wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/codesample/plugin.min.js loaded by tinyMCE init method. We have to add tinyMCE editor in the page. It is there for comments. For other pages(preview mode for example) I load it manually: `wp_editor( '', 'load_tinymce', array(
                'editor_css' => '<style>#wp-load_tinymce-wrap {display:none;}</style>'
                ));` so this js file will be loaded with tinyMCE

Comment: I think you are missing something. (i) We are not just discussing about tinymce, but through a wordpress plugin, how to load a tinymce plugin (ii) you have mentioned, wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/codesample/plugin.min.js loaded by tinyMCE init method. But this plugin itself does not come with Wordpress nor tinymce. If you use standalone tinymce, you have to upload this plugin to wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/codesample/. Many plugins does not come with tinymce and hence you won’t find it in that plugin folder

Comment: The solution to create a Wordpress plugin where tinymce will use the codesample plugin (not present by default in tinymce plugins folder) - use the add_filter( 'mce_external_plugins', 'my_custom_plugins' ); and function my_custom_plugins( $plugins ) {$plugins['codesample'] = plugins_url( 'tinymce/', __FILE__ ) . 'codesample/plugin.min.js'; return $plugins;}You will also have to create another filter for the Tinymce init i.e., to initialize the plugin and toolbar  add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', ‘mytheme_tinymce_settings‘)..underscores not shown in FILE

Comment: @Jay Yes, sorry. Codesample is it in wordpress tinyMCE for now. I just copied it from tinymce dev version downloaded from tinymce site. Thanks for this point

Answer (score 0):

The `codesample` plugin relies on Prism.js (and a CSS file) to handle the syntax highlighting in TinyMCE.  This is documented here:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/codesample/

You likely just need to add Prism.js and Prism.css to your rendered page to get the highlighting.  This is documented here:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/codesample/#usingprismjsonyourwebpage

Comment: Yes, thank you. Already found it. But also I found that to run codesample plugin on page you have to call `tinymce.codesampleplugin.Prism.highlightAll()` from javascript

Comment: I have not done anything like that. To render it in any front-end page, you need to have the prism.js and prism.css. This requires the least amount of coding. Prior to this Oxe Labs code editor, I have written another editor, which simply adds a <pre><code> tags to the active selected item, which is much bigger than the OxeLabs editor. Check my plugin written for Code Labs. https://github.com/jay3000bc/wordpress/tree/master/plugins/OxeLabs%20Code%20Editor

Comment: Can I use codesample without Prism to just get the code block without formatting?